# redirecting and keeping the format of the output from diff + bash

Tags: bash, diff

I have these 2 files file1.txt

```
$ cat file1.txt
I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.
I need to wash the dog.
I need to get the car detailed.
```

and file2.txt

```
$ cat file2.txt
I need to buy apples.
I need to do the laundry.
I need to wash the car.
I need to get the dog detailed.
```

I want to see the difference in files using the `diff` command and display it using the `-y` option.

```
$ diff --width=250 -y file1.txt file2.txt
I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples.               |   I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.                                                                                                  |   I need to do the laundry.
I need to wash the dog.                                                                                                     |   I need to wash the car.
I need to get the car detailed.                                                                                             |   I need to get the dog detailed.
```

I want to be able to redirect the output of `diff` above but I want to keep the format as above.

I am having trouble doing this. Can it be done?

```
$ echo $(diff --width=250 -y file1.txt file2.txt)
I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. | I need to buy apples. I need to run the laundry. | I need to do the laundry. I need to wash the dog. | I need to wash the car. I need to get the car detailed. | I need to get the dog detailed.
```

I would also like to know how many characters(including spaces) is in the the longest line in the file1.txt.
I have tried the below but no joy. Can this be done?

```
$ wc -L file1.txt
109 file1.txt
```

Comment: Double-quote the `$()` part.

Comment: What's the issue with the longest line command? If you want only the number, you can use `wc -L < file1.txt`.

Comment: for your first question: `tr '\n' ' '` for your second one, I don't know what's wrong with `wc` command.

Comment: @Josh @ qqibrow ah i though 109 was not including spaces, my mistaket the reason i asked was `109` was not working in here`diff --width=109 -y file1.txt file2.txt` the columns was still too short. what am i not understaning?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the there is enough space to show all lines completely, use:

```
diff --width=$(( $(cat file1.txt file2.txt|wc -L)*2+3 )) -y file1.txt file2.txt
```

One might naively think that the width required by `diff` would be related to the sum of the maximum length of lines in each file.  It isn't.

To keep the newline characters when using `echo`, double-quotes are required:

```
$ echo "$(diff --width=$(( $(cat file1.txt file2.txt|wc -L)*2+3 )) -y file1.txt file2.txt)"
I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. I need to buy apples. | I need to buy apples.
I need to run the laundry.                                                                                    | I need to do the laundry.
I need to wash the dog.                                                                                       | I need to wash the car.
I need to get the car detailed.                                                                               | I need to get the dog detailed
```

.

Comment: why the `*2+3`? I am getting `109` for `cat file1.txt file2.txt|wc -L` is this not the number of characters?

Comment: @HattrickNZ `--width` refers to diff's output, not its input.  109 is the maximum line width in _either_ file, not the width that `diff` needs to display them both _side-by-side_.  `diff` wants 109 characters for the first file, _and_ 109 characters for the second file _plus_ 3 characters for the divider: space bar space.  Thus, the total width that `diff` wants is 109 times two plus three.

Comment: tks  I thought the 109 was per column(per diff output) but that makes sense.

Comment: @HattrickNZ diff's documentation on this could be a lot better.  For example, for files with short lines, diff needs up to 7 spaces for the divider instead of the the 3 used here.  None of this is documented.